# Error "Function 'subsindex' is not defined for values of class 'embedded.fi'." When Changing Matlab Version

Tags: matlab

I have a struct 'ss' in Matlab that has a number of fields that are all zero'd in the beginning.

Declarations:

```
 ss = struct;
 ss.angle_spit = zeros(ais,his,tis,2);
 ss.angle_neck = zeros(ais,his,tis,2);
```

I then go into a for loop and each iteration I update these values like such.

```
ss.angle_spit(ai,hi,fi,ti,1) = angle_spit_d;
ss.angle_spit(ai,hi,fi,ti,2) = angle_spit_u;
```

I was running this code on Matlab version R2015a with no errors, however, when I started to run it on a different computer running R2012a it gives me the error

```
"Error using subsindex
Function 'subsindex' is not defined for values of class 'embedded.fi'.

Error in spit_additup_11a_for12long3_fixqs (line 409) 
ss.angle_spit(ai,hi,fi,ti,1) = angle_spit_d;"
```

My understanding is that I am trying to index the struct and that is not a possibility in 2012 and it is in 2015. Am I correct in assuming this, and if so, how would you go about changing the code to support this in 2012? Would you just create many more fields for the struct? Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are creating an index *variable* called `fi` and it's being confused with the *function* [`fi`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/fixedpoint/ref/fi.html) from the [Fixed-Point Designer](https://www.mathworks.com/help/fixedpoint/index.html). When you try to use it as an index into the structure field `ss.angle_spit`, it throws the given error. The version-dependence of the error is more likely a dependence on whether the Fixed-Point Designer is included with your installation or not.

Try renaming `fi` to something else. I would expect that to fix the problem.

On a broader note, you should avoid giving variables the same name as an existing function, since it can either shadow that function or lead to strange behavior like you're seeing. As such, you should also rename your structure variable, since `ss` is already an [existing function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/ss.html).

Comment: Thank you! That is exactly what happened.